# Mac or PC for a CS Major?

Tags: windows, winforms, macos, operating-system, computer-science

I am a graduating senior from high school and I plan to attend college in the fall of 2014. I plan to be a CS major, and I am just curious what you all think of in regard of what computer to purchase for CS.

I am open to all opinions, and please explain your reasoning behind your choice.

Your fellow programmer,

Justin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go for Linux based OS and play with the source code during your CS.

PC and Mac are for users, but you do not want to become a user but a programmer, so Linux based OS are best as they are open source and you can learn a lot.

Analogy:

- a TV user - knows how to use the buttons on the outside of the TV
- a TV manufacturer - places those electronics components there on the board
- a TV designer - knows why those components are there

To become a good programmer, you must [MUST] know how and why of the codes that you will write.

Comment: Theoretically, this seems like a good idea. Practically, this seems like a good way to need at least one fresh install if one isn't rather careful about what bit of source code is being modified, and that's something to avoid doing while in college as if the timing is bad it'll end up hurting your final grades. When your just starting college it's probably going to make things a lot easier on you to be a user than a programmer at least for a while. Thought the bit about being a good programmer is good, it may not be wise to jump in that deep too quickly.

Comment: @Nuclearman: I suppose he is already a user of either Windows or Mac. One can always work with dual boot or VMs to prevent the last minute issues.

Answer (score 2):

A Mac might just be a better option only if you would consider dual booting windows? Otherwise go with a PC, because of the higher flexibility and software options.